# Hiding a field in Lightning components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, validation-rule

How to hide a field in lightning component.

```
 <tr class="slds-hint-parent slds-has-divider--top" >
    <td class="slds-size--3-of-12">
           <span class="slds-truncate">Fire</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="slds-truncate"><a href="" onclick="{!c.gotoFire}"  id="      {!v.CampaignObj.Business_Unit__r.Fire__c}"> {!v.CampaignObj.Business_Unit__r.Fire__c}</a></span>
    </td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Need to hide the label "Fire" from the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Lightning Components Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm) has a good example on how to do that.

Basically you need to add a class to your label. Example:

```html
<!--c:toggleCss-->
<aura:component>
    <ui:button label="Toggle" press="{!c.toggle}"/>
    <span aura:id="text" class="slds-truncate">Fire</span>
</aura:component>
```

```javascript
/*toggleCssController.js*/
({
    toggle : function(component, event, helper) {
        var toggleText = component.find("text");
        $A.util.toggleClass(toggleText, "toggle");
    }
})
```

```css
/*toggleCss.css*/
.THIS.toggle {
    display: none;
}
```